# How to solve grid and box error in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a GridLayout in my Xamarin.Forms App. But my App I used BoxView. So in here I want to reduse size in that boxview. in my app when I clicked exixting user its working nicely but when I click new radio button getting crashing. in my app, but in my code its not like that. And I would like each element in the grid as shown here:

[Click me and help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AZG3.jpg)
[Existing and help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JP03.jpg)

```xml
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <ScrollView>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Padding="20">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="addressBoxViewRow" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="Care of User - Address" Grid.Row="0" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Default" TextColor="Black" />
                        <Label Text="Enter the details of the person that the connection will be in care of." TextColor="#757575" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="Small" />
                        <FlexLayout Grid.Row="2" AlignItems="Center" JustifyContent="Start" Direction="Row">
                            <Label Text="Address status" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
                            <input:RadioButtonGroupView Margin="20,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="addressStatus" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <input:RadioButton Text="New" TextFontSize="14" x:Name="newRadioButton" Clicked="NewRadioButton_Clicked" />
                                <input:RadioButton Text="Existing" IsChecked="true" TextFontSize="14" x:Name="existingRadioButton" Clicked="ExistingRadioButton_Clicked" />
                            </input:RadioButtonGroupView>
                        </FlexLayout>
                        <BoxView Grid.Row="3" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="5">
                            <BoxView.Effects>
                                <effects:ShadowEffect />
                            </BoxView.Effects>
                        </BoxView>
                        <!--This appears when Existing selected-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Padding="20" x:Name="existingAddressForm">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Billing address" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Default" TextColor="Black" />
                            <Label Text="Address line 1" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" x:Name="lblAddressLine1" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                            <Label Text="Address line 2" Grid.Row="3" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="4" x:Name="lblAddressLine2" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                            <Label Text="Address line 3" Grid.Row="5" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="6" x:Name="lblAddressLine3" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                            <Label Text="Postal code" Grid.Row="7" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="8" x:Name="lblPostalCode" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                        </Grid>
                        <!--This appears when New selected-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Padding="20" x:Name="newAddressForm">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Billing address" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Default" TextColor="Black" />
                            <Label Text="Address line 1" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                            <Entry Grid.Row="2" x:Name="addressLine1" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                            <Label Text="Address line 2" Grid.Row="3" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                            <Entry Grid.Row="4" x:Name="addressLine2" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                            <Label Text="Address line 3" Grid.Row="5" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                            <Entry Grid.Row="6" x:Name="addressLine3" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                            <Label Text="Postal code" Grid.Row="7" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                            <Picker Grid.Row="8" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" x:Name="postalCodeSelector1" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding PostalDescription}" WidthRequest="100">
                                <Picker.Effects>
                                    <effects:DropdownEffect />
                                </Picker.Effects>
                            </Picker>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End">
                        <Button Text="Clear" Style="{x:StaticResource GrayButton}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="ClearBtn_Clicked"/>
                        <Button Text="Proceed" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" x:Name="proceedBtn" />
                    </StackLayout>

                    <!--<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" BackgroundColor="White" Opacity="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <ActivityIndicator Color="#2B428E" IsRunning="true" />
                            <Label x:Name="progressname" Text="Please wait ..." TextColor="#2B428E" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>-->
                </Grid>
            </ScrollView>
        </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: So you have two App? One Xamarin.Forms based App and another App? By the way where does this control come from  input:RadioButtonGroupView

Comment: @MouseOnMars Can you check my attached picture

Comment: @MouseOnMars No same Ui. When click one radio button open some boxview in same Ui

Comment: @JohnLee Can you show the screenshot of "existing"?

Comment: @AndroDevil https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JP03.jpg

Comment: @JohnLee so what is exactly your problem? Is it the extra space at the bottom? or app carsh?

Comment: @AndroDevil Extra space at the bottom.

Comment: You can solve it by providing <RowDefinition x:Name="addressBoxViewRow" Height="300" />.   You are not setting the height of this row

Comment: @AndroDevil not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Padding="20">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                    <RowDefinition x:Name="addressBoxViewRow" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Text="Care of User - Address" Grid.Row="0" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Default" TextColor="Black" />
                <Label Text="Enter the details of the person that the connection will be in care of." TextColor="#757575" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="Small" />
                <FlexLayout Grid.Row="2" AlignItems="Center" JustifyContent="Start" Direction="Row">
                    <Label Text="Address status" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
                    <input:RadioButtonGroupView Margin="20,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="addressStatus" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <input:RadioButton Text="New" TextFontSize="14" x:Name="newRadioButton" Clicked="NewRadioButton_Clicked" />
                        <input:RadioButton Text="Existing" IsChecked="true" TextFontSize="14" x:Name="existingRadioButton" Clicked="ExistingRadioButton_Clicked" />
                    </input:RadioButtonGroupView>
                </FlexLayout>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="3" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="5">
                    <BoxView.Effects>
                        <effects:ShadowEffect />
                    </BoxView.Effects>
                </BoxView>
                <!--This appears when Existing selected-->
                <Grid Grid.Row="3" Padding="20" x:Name="existingAddressForm">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Billing address" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Default" TextColor="Black" />
                    <Label Text="Address line 1" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" x:Name="lblAddressLine1" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                    <Label Text="Address line 2" Grid.Row="3" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="4" x:Name="lblAddressLine2" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                    <Label Text="Address line 3" Grid.Row="5" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="6" x:Name="lblAddressLine3" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                    <Label Text="Postal code" Grid.Row="7" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="8" x:Name="lblPostalCode" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                </Grid>
                <!--This appears when New selected-->
                <Grid Grid.Row="3" Padding="20" x:Name="newAddressForm">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Billing address" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Default" TextColor="Black" />
                    <Label Text="Address line 1" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                    <Entry Grid.Row="2" x:Name="addressLine1" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                    <Label Text="Address line 2" Grid.Row="3" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                    <Entry Grid.Row="4" x:Name="addressLine2" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                    <Label Text="Address line 3" Grid.Row="5" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                    <Entry Grid.Row="6" x:Name="addressLine3" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" />
                    <Label Text="Postal code" Grid.Row="7" TextColor="#757575" FontSize="Small" />
                    <Picker Grid.Row="8" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" x:Name="postalCodeSelector1" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding PostalDescription}" WidthRequest="100">
                        <Picker.Effects>
                            <effects:DropdownEffect />
                        </Picker.Effects>
                    </Picker>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End">
                <Button Text="Clear" Style="{x:StaticResource GrayButton}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="ClearBtn_Clicked"/>
                <Button Text="Proceed" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" x:Name="proceedBtn" />
            </StackLayout>

            <!--<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" BackgroundColor="White" Opacity="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <ActivityIndicator Color="#2B428E" IsRunning="true" />
                        <Label x:Name="progressname" Text="Please wait ..." TextColor="#2B428E" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>-->
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: the extra space didnt reduced?

Comment: Hi @AndroDevil I chenged code <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> to <RowDefinition Height="*" /> then it's working. Thanks for helping me